# Admins locked out of hacked Facebook page – no contact form

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, hacked

An official page I manage is seemingly hacked, as all admins lost all access to it.

Where can I report it to Facebook and regain access?

I tried to look for such an option for hours, but nothing found...very annoying.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: [I think my Facebook Page was hacked or taken over by someone else](https://m.facebook.com/help/738660629556925)

Comment: @Blindspots This was indeed one of the links that I've found and doesn't work. It leads me to a form that just says an error... https://i.imgur.com/xd3PDaW.png

Comment: Either an admin removed your access or an Admin's account was hacked. If their account was hacked they should report it. If they removed your access they need to restore it.  We don't have enough info to help you but you should be able to narrow it down. The page hasn't been hacked.

Comment: The issue is narrowed down absolutely. A hacker got access through one of the admins (and all other pages of that admin were hacked as well), and the hacker outruled all other admins from all pages. Then appeared for a "ransom".

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

Based on the details provided:

1. A Facebook user had Facebook access with full control to a page<sup>*****</sup>.
2. That user's account was compromised.
3. The account's page access was used to change the users with page access and/or their access permissions.

<sup><sup>*****</sup> *It's unclear what you meant by "official" page.*</sup>

### Actions You Should Take

None. In the absence of any additional mitigating details, your account doesn't factor into this as it was not compromised.

Your access to the page was removed using another user's legitimate permissions. It is the owner of the compromised account that needs support and any request to reverse those changes must come from them. They should report it to Facebook who will be able to confirm the account was compromised and take appropriate action.

### Facebook Resources:

- [Report a compromised account](https://www.facebook.com/hacked)
- [Help with a hacked account (Guided)](https://www.facebook.com/help/1306725409382822/)

### Page Management

The term "Manage" covers both **Facebook access** and **Task access** to a page. Within those two access types, there are further role/privilege customization options:

1. **`Facebook access`**
   Access to a page with either **full** or **partial** control.
2. **`Task access`**
   No page access but instead access to specific tasks (as allowed) via Facebook tools such as the Meta Business Suite, Business Manager, and the Ads Manager.

### Notes

There are a lot of details that are absent such as who is the page owner, the type of page being discussed, the nature of the compromise, what actions have been taken to date by the user whose account was compromised, and why you are pursuing this in their stead.

Comment: You basically say that I didn't provide some detail. What exactly? I was admin on the page, and also another person, who reported that other pages under her administration as well were hacked as well. So probably her account is compromised. Currently, no admin can access the page, except the hacker. The facebook.com/hacked page we visited already, it doesn't seem to advance the case of regaining the access. It just solved a password change. What else information do you need?